# getting program uptime

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, uptime

I'm beginner to programming. This is my code:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sec++;
    textBoxSeconds.Text = sec.ToString();
    if (sec > 59)
    {
        sec = 0;
        textBoxSeconds.Text = sec.ToString();
        min++;
        textBoxMinutes.Text = min.ToString();
    }
}
```

time goes too fast;/ and it stops for few sec sometimes. **Hope someone can help me:)**
**EDIT//**
thanks for help:) it works, but i still have a problem i didnt menton earlier. time stops sometimes for 1-2 sec, idk why. maybe because of some loops?

Comment: *"time stops sometimes for 1-2 sec"* - it sounds like you are blocking the UI thread, hence the UI does not update in that time ("freezes") - long running operations should be done on a different thread, e.g. using the BackgroundWorker. That problem is not in the code you are showing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the wrong approach. When you program starts just save a `DateTime` instance, i.e. `startTime`. In your timer tick handler calculate the difference between the current time and the start time and display that.

```
private DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var delta = DateTime.Now - startTime;
    textBoxSeconds.Text = delta.Seconds.ToString("n0");
    textBoxMinutes.Text = Math.Floor(delta.TotalMinutes).ToString("n0");
}
```

Comment: Sorry for messing with your answer :-)

Comment: @dtb: your change works, thanks ;-) - I had assumed there were more textboxes for hours etc. so I didn't worry about rollover

Comment: DateTime.Now is wrong approach too... You should always use DataTime.UtcNow for internal calculations and persistence, unless it is bound to day frame (like in meeting schedulers, e.t.c.). In your case it prevents you from error if time zone will be changed while program is running.

Answer (score 1):

Using your code, I can say probably you haven't set the timer `Interval`, so:

`timer1.Interval = 1000; //1000 ms = 1 second`

Then you can improve something in the `Tick` event:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sec++;

    if (sec == 60)
    {
        sec = 0;
        min++;
    }

    textBoxSeconds.Text = sec.ToString();
    textBoxMinutes.Text = min.ToString();
}
```

So use the [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.datetime.aspx) class, it's the best solution.

**EDIT:**

```
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

    void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan time = DateTime.Now - startTime;
        textBoxSeconds.Text = string.Format("{0:0#}", time.Seconds);
        textBoxMinutes.Text = string.Format("{0:0#}", time.Minutes);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree about startTime - it is mandatory. I've also commented about DataTime.UtcNow - this is correct way.

About your second problem with 1..2 seconds lag - this is because timer's ticks racing side by side with seconds ticks.

1) If your timer will be triggered in 998ms instead of 1000ms, you can read the same amount of second and this number will stay before next tick.

2) Because application is not in real-time priority from OS point of view, it can be held for several seconds (e.g. for rendering multimedia stuff by other app) and you can notice a skip of 1 second...

To solve 1st reason and facilitate 2nd try to increase ticks count by decreasing Interval to 500 or 333.

For more advanced strategy that preserves your resources, you should still use 1000ms but synchronize you timer periodically with each half second crossing using dateTime.Milliseconds. That will maximize probability of avoiding side-by-side racing problem without extra ticks.